# Flexbox - Distribute items in column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a *flexbox layout* like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item1, .item2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nested_left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.nested_right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nested_left">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/any" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested_right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the left column have space in between the images so that the top image is aligned at the top, and the bottom one at the bottom.

I can do this when using `flex-direction: row` but not when I am using `column`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `justify-content: space-between` on the `.nested_left` *div*, which will put them apart as much as it can:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row; by default*/
}
 
.item1, .item2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
 
.nested_left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid green;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 
img {display: block} /* to remove bottom margin/whitespace */
 
.nested_right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nested_left">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/any" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested_right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

It's worth to mention that when using `flex-direction: column`, the *main* and *cross-axis* switch, which then makes the `justify-content` *property* affect the *y-axis*.

Answer (score 0):

just give

```
.nested-left { 
   justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

```css
 .container {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
 }
 
 .item1,.item2{
   border:1px solid black;
 }
 
 .nested_left {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
    border:2px solid green;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
 .nested_right {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   border:2px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nested_left">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/any">
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/any">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested_right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </div>
</div>
```